# C++ and SDL: Why can't I compile this program?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, sdl

For some reason I can't compile this program because I'm supposedly missing SDL. It compiles fine on Debug mode, but not Release. I am using Visual C++ 2010. I linked to SDL with VC++ directories. Here is my (little) code.

```
//main.cpp
#include "main.h"

void logger::log(string logging)
{
    file << logging << "\n";
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    logger logObj;
        logObj.log("uShootZombies started.");

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
        logObj.log("SDL initalized.");

    SDL_Quit();
        logObj.log("SDL quit.");

    return 0;
}


//main.h
#include <SDL.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class game
{
    public:
    private:
};

class logger
{
    public:
    void log(string logging);
    logger()
    {
        file.open("Log.txt", ios::out);
    }

    ~logger()
    {
        file.close();
    }
    private:
    ofstream file;
};
```

What am I doing wrong? If you need more info just ask. ;)

Comment: In Visual Studio, different configurations (Debug, Release, different CPUs) have different settings.  Even though you added the correct directories and libraries for Debug, you have to make the same changes for Release in order for it to compile correctly.

Comment: Are you sure that you're linking against SDL library in **both** configurations (Debug and Release) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be sure you added your library references to release mode as well as debug mode.  I'm not 100% sure about SDL but some 3rd party libraries come with 2 flavors, debug & release. I believe you'll have to setup the release mode of the IDE with the release mode of the library files.

Answer (score 2):

Open your project properties and verify that you're linking against the SDL library in both Debug and Release configurations : there is a combo box in the upper left corner of the property dialog where you can select the configuration to edit.